# How to containerize MySQL using Docker for Docker Compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to containerize MySQL for my application, using Docker. The backend is made using Spring Boot, the frontend consists of Angular code. I am using MySQL as the database.

I have created a Docker-compose.yml for the backend and frontend. However, I have no clue how to add a "build mysql image too" part in the .yml file. I want to achieve these two things -

1. Build the image for mysql, from the docker-compose.yml
2. Use that mysql container and open it's bash to dump a few rows of data to the database. (By using docker exec -it db bash)

How do I achieve these? I have installed MySQL for Ubuntu. I have no clue how to proceed, i.e., whether I need to pull the MySQL image or not. Can anyone help me with a step-by-step method?

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: sqldocker
    ports:
           -  "3306:3306"
    environment:
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
           - MYSQL_USER=root
           - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
           - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
    volumes:
           - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
           test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
           timeout: 20s
           retries: 10
    restart: always
  backendserver:
    build: ./docker-demo-backend/
    ports:
           - "8080:8080"
    links:
           - "db"
    depends_on:
           - "db"
    restart: always
  frontend:
    build: ./docker-demo-frontend/
    links:
           - "backendserver"
    depends_on:
           - "backendserver"
    ports:
           - "80:80"
```

Comment: why have you build image, why do not use existing mysql image?

Comment: In case of that, how can I use the existing image? How do I specify that in the yml file? Like... for the image directory, I have to use "build: "..

Comment: you just have to specify `image` instead of `build`:
```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ... ```
https://medium.com/@chrischuck35/how-to-create-a-mysql-instance-with-docker-compose-1598f3cc1bee

Comment: Getting this error: Named volume "my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Comment: add at the end on the same level with `services` - `volumes:
           my-datavolume:`

Comment: I commented out the "volumes" line to make it default. Now, the docker-compose command is successfully executing. But, one problem is still there. The MySQL service is being run with default (empty) password. I did specify the custom password in the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fully workable example how to start up mysql with docker composer. You can apply it for yourself:
version: '3.3'

```
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

[Official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/)

Comment: Mysql is initializing with empty password! Is there a workaround?

Comment: it isn't. after you up your docker compose try that: `docker exec -it mysql-container-id bash` then `env | grep -i password` and see what password is

Comment: it is showing that it has initialized with empty pass, in the build log

Comment: i have executed the command you suggested. it is showing "failed to create runc console socket: mkdir /tmp/pty318963545: no such file or directory: unknown"

Comment: show that log. could you connect with empty pass if you can please provide commands you execute

Comment: db_1             | 2019-11-05T11:30:02.390207Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

Comment: after `image` in compose file add `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

Comment: Thanks. Trying that. But, how do I specify the password? I do have env variables in the yml file. Why is it not taking it?

Comment: if you initial question is resolved please mark answer respectively

Comment: It isn't resolved, actually. Previously, too, it was initializing without password. That's why I'm having to ask.

Comment: That was gone after providing `command` : ` [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.`

Comment: and it uses root pass from env variables I provided: `mysql -Uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` but `mysql -Uroot -psomewordpress
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure`